# SvelteKit routes go to redirect loop when put behind NGINX reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, nginx, routes, proxy, sveltekit

I have a SvelteKit website with several routes (let's say `/` and `/about/`), running on a Node.js server with `adapter-node`. When started locally with `npm run build` then `node build`, everything works and all routes are accessible: i.e. loading `localhost:3000/` opens homepage, `localhost:3000/about` opens the about page.

However, when I try to put the Node server behind an nginx reverse proxy with conditional routing, all routes except the top-level domain stop working, and go into a redirect loop (`301` -> `308` -> `301` -> `...`). What am I doing wrong?

The nginx server is exposed to external HTTP(S) traffic, and is set up to route all website-related requests to the Node/SvelteKit server, ***but*** some requests (`/api/*`) need to go to another service on another port (`4000`). Because of that, simply forwarding all requests from nginx to SvelteKit with `location / { ... }` isn't possible. Here is how the routing is set up currently:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes 1;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    # SvelteKit server on port 3000
    upstream website {
        server website_server:3000;
    }

    # Another server for /api/ on port 4000
    upstream apis {
        server api_server:4000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl; 
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
        server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

        # Route all /api/ requests to API server
        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://apis;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }

        # Route website requests to SvelteKit
        location = / {
            proxy_pass http://website;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
        location = /about/ {
            # ... Same contents as previous location block
        }
        location /_app/ {
            # ... Same contents as previous location block
        }
        location /images/ {
            # ... Same contents as previous location block
        }
        location /css/ {
            # ... Same contents as previous location block
        }
        location /fonts/ {
            # ... Same contents as previous location block
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inspecting the requests and redirects, the issue ended up being about trailing slashes. [SvelteKit removes all trailing slashes by default](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/page-options#trailingslash), which means requests to `/about/` would get redirected to `/about`. However, the NGINX configuration is set up with the `/about/` route, so it will redirect the `/about` request back to `/about/`, resulting in the loop.

To fix this, several things can be done:

1. The `nginx.conf` file can be edited, to add a route not containing a trailing slash.

```
location = /about { 
   # same contents as /about/
}
```

*Note:* It's better to add this route *without* removing the existing trailing slash route. If `/about/` is removed, loading `/about` will work, but `/about/` won't. If both routes are present, SvelteKit will redirect `/about/` to `/about`, and both requests will correctly resolve.

2. SvelteKit can be configured not to remove trailing slashes. In the `+layout.server.js` file, add the line `export const trailingSlash = 'always';`

These two approaches are slightly different. Approach 1 will make keep route requests absolute, so if the page references any static assets (i.e. the `/about` page loads an image from `/images/logo.jpg`), they will correctly resolve to the base path.

Approach 2 will make route requests relative, which means all consequent requests will start from the subpath, making `/about/images/logo.jpg` the new resource path. Since this isn't desired behaviour, approach 1 will fit most use cases better.